# Create menu context with jquery or query selector

Tags: html, jquery, css, menu, queryselector

I want to create a menu context. But I am stuck while clicking and then hiding. I am using ul li for menu

I have used addeventlistner and mousedown function which hides menu. I have used a little bit this code.

```
<div class="context">
  <ul>
    <li>add</li>
    <li>copy</li>
    <li>paste</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  var context = queryselector(".context")
  function showmenu(){
    document.addeventlistner("mousedown", onmousedown, false)
  }
  function mousedown(){
    menuhide()
    document.removeeventlistner("mousedown", onmousedown)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please look at code. A little bit same. I have remembered this chunk. I have no laptop at that time